# What is the grammar for the following context-free language $L=\{w|w=a^ib^ja^jb^{i}\}$?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I want to find the grammar for the following context-free language:

$L=\{w|w=a^ib^ja^jb^{i}\}$

I tried

\begin{align*}
S&\rightarrow \varepsilon|aKb |aSb\\
K&\rightarrow\varepsilon |bKa
\end{align*}

I want to know if it works for any cas. It works for the following example $aababb$ :

\begin{align}
aSb (1)\\
S(1)&\rightarrow aKb(2)\\
K(2)&\rightarrow bKa(3)\\
K(3)&\rightarrow \varepsilon\\
\end{align}

Something is missing: the grammar rule we use. If you have also a better way to explain the outpu, I would be glad to hear it from you !

- In parenthesis it is the step in which we are on the right of the arrow and which we use on the left.
- In indice it is the position of the character we change.

Comment: So you'd use the first rule $i$ times and second rule $j$ times? BTW, I'm not sure what your questions are. I understand the question about if it works for any cas, but not the part after the production rules.

Comment: Do you allow $i$ and $j$ to be zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow $i=0$, then the grammar you give does not generate $b^ja^j$. Try the one below:
$$S\rightarrow \varepsilon\;|\;aKb\;|\;bHa$$
$$K\rightarrow \varepsilon\;|\;aKb\;|\;bHa$$
$$H\rightarrow \varepsilon\;|\;bHa$$